# Examples for practicing reverse engineering/disassembly of win32 .executables

Tags: windows, exploit, reverse-engineering, license-enforcement

I remember back in the day, there used to be a website where users would post hackits in the form of win32 exes for users to crack. Usually the goal was to defeat some sort of DRM, such as a nag screen, etc. The challenges would be classified by skill level- ranging from beginner to intermediate and so on. I can't find the website or similar resources.

Do you know of any such resource where users could practice their reverse engineering skills (particularly in the win32 domain)?

Comment: not sure but this might help u http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/265/where-to-find-free-training-in-reverse-engineering

Comment: @Lonelybaby : Wow. I didn't even know that there was a reverseengineering.stackexchange even! Thanks for that. I think cracksme.de is closest to what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://crackmes.de/ is perhaps the most comprehensive website in this category.

Also Keygen challenges at http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.51 are good .